# Remove jtoolbars floating indicator

Tags: java, floating, indicator, jtoolbar

im trying to remove/edit the floating indicator from a jtoolbar while still being able to float the jtoolbar. Unfortunately i cant find the method in the jtoolbarui that creates the border. does anybody know how its called?

Answer (score 0):

setBorderPainted(false) in the jtoolbar disables the floating indicator